y-axis being automatically shifted; centered on zero
I'm trying to make a simple line plot where all the values around very close to 1. However, when I plot it the y-axis gets shifted down so all values are centered around 0. It indicates this with a +1 at the top of the y-axis. How do I make it stop shifting the y-axis?
Simple reproducer:
import numpy as np
import datetime

vals = np.random.uniform(0.9999, 1.0001, 100)
dates = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(len(vals))]

plt.plot(dates, vals)
plt.show()

This code results in the following graph. It looks the same through Pycharm and when run from the terminal using PyQt6.


Does this answer your question? Prevent scientific notation

You can adjust the format like this:
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', useOffset=False)

see this documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html
import numpy as np
import datetime

vals = np.random.uniform(0.9999, 1.0001, 100)
dates = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(len(vals))]

plt.plot(dates, vals)
plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', useOffset=False)
plt.show()


dupe
